# How To Show Topic Details for Multiple Sections in Segue

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, segue, master-detail

I created a splitview master-detail application that has a single section with 135+ topics, and it works like a charm.  I decided to add an index list along the RH side to help the user scroll through the topics listing, but when I did that, I no longer know how to show the details for the topics in each subsequent section after 0.  The index list shows correctly along the RH side and all the topics display correctly in the topics tableview with their appropriate section headings.  But, if I select a topic in the second section, or subsequent sections, the selected topic details are always for the section 0 topics.

Here is the segue method where I believe the problem lies.  I'm not sure how to show the appropriate topic details for sections 1 + n.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showTopicDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let topics = self.topics[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

            //Loads data set for selected topic to segue
            controller.topics = topics

            //adds selected topic as detailViewController page title
            controller.title = topics.topic

            // Ads breadcrumb button to go back the Topics list
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something else I need to add to this question to get a response.  I admit I am not a highly skilled iOS programmer, but I am striving to learn.